# Azure B2C secured API can't be called when logged in using social providers

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have an angular website which is secured using Azure AD B2C. B2C is configured with local accounts and three social providers (MS, Google & Facebook) and everything from the web app perspective works great.

The web app calls a separate .NET Core web API which has a couple of secured endpoints. The web API has been set up as an application in B2C with all of the relevant scopes and the scopes have then been added to the web app as described in the getting started docs from MS.

If I'm logged in to the web app using a local account the API call's work perfectly however if I'm logged in using a social provider they fail. In the case of an MS account I see the following:

```
Frame with URL 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=omitted for brevity'
attempted to navigate its top-level window with origin 'https://localhost:44314'.
Navigating the top-level window from a cross-origin iframe will soon require that the iframe has received a user gesture.
See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5851021045661696.
```

Google and Facebook provide similar errors. It looks to me like somewhere along the line a redirect is being initiated to try and log in again.

On the Angualr app I'm using msal-angular (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular) which is configured as described in the link.

I've scoured the docs and google to try to find a solution but to no avail so any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure if I'm just running into something that's not currently supported in B2C.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @AndyM. Does this occur immediately after logging in or later after the access token is about to expire or has expired?

Comment: Hi @ChrisPadgett thanks for the question. It's immediately after login, can't be more than 10 seconds between logging in and accessing the pages which call the APIs

Comment: Hi @ChrisPadgett appologies for following this up but any ideas? I'm going to submit an issues on the MSAL GitHub repo in a couple of days if I've not managed to get a solution. Many thanks, Andy